# Godot: how to implement 2d fixed joint?

Tags: 2d, game-physics, rigid-bodies, godot

So, I'm starting with Godot, relying on the physics engine (RigidBody2D-based) for a 2d top-down spaceship game.  Part of the idea is that the spacecraft are modular - i.e. parts can be assembled in different ways to create different craft.  It's still in early stages, but what I'm looking at currently is how best to attach these different parts.  Earlier I implemented a rotating cannon and attached it to the ship using Joint2D, and that works well, but for non-rotating parts, Godot doesn't have a "fixed" joint as such.  The only way I have seen to do a fixed joint so far is two pin joints with some distance between them.  (Yay for a background in engineering).

But, I see a few issues with this: (1) that many joints could be adding extra computational load for when I create more and larger craft (seeing as all I want it to do is act like a single rigid body), (2) it's more work to actually assemble the parts (eventually I'm hoping to add a ship editor, and attach parts programmatically - I do realise this point will be fairly easy to solve), (3) am I going to run into issues with complex builds later on?, and (4) how well will the physics engine handle these kinds of assemblies?

Would I be better to have the non-moving ship parts added as part of the same rigid body, rather than separate pieces?  However, if I do that, will things like losing a module, having separate hitpoints for each part, etc end up being more difficult?

I'm not sure I want to do this last part, but what about semi-rigid (i.e. flexible) joints?  In other words, a flexible spacecraft?  (An early version of the game concept was to use real physics from the ground up - including things like various modes of material failure - but soft bodies are difficult, so I'm not going there... at least not for the foreseeable future!)

Answer (score -2):

No need for a fixed joint in Godot. You can add multiple collision shapes under a RigidBody2D.

So, add all your collisions shapes -- along with any additional sprites -- under the RigidBody2D node, and they will all act together as one solid object.

Comment: Thanks, but how will this work in terms of each of those items taking damage separately and consequently being destroyed separately (and thus removed from the "tree")?  Will that work?  The whole idea of the game is that parts acting separately matters.

Comment: Yes. You can use the `body_shape_entered` signal of the RigidBody2D to detect which parts of it are taking damage (see the `local_shape` parameter) and then remove the sprite and the collision shape for any part that has taken too much damage.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I agree that in many cases this might be the correct solution. At the same time an engine shouldn't be so restrictive. There are other cases where joints would need to be fixed

Comment: @MarcJames If you have other cases where you need fixed joints, please post them as separate questions. My post answers the original poster's question. It's absurd to downvote this because it doesn't solve some other issue you're having, when it gives a very valid, working solution to the original question.

Comment: I disagree because of your statement "No need for a fixed join in Godot."

Comment: @MarcJames Please post your "other cases" as separate questions, so people can either help you with a solution where you think you need a fixed joint, or learn from you if there truly is a case where a fixed joint is needed. Godot's paradigm is quite different than other engines you may be familiar with; adding multiple collision shapes under a RigidBody2D acts as an equivalent to fixed joints.